# Salesforce Einstein Bot close and minimize button getting enlarged

Tags: salesforce-einstein

I have a working react app which has multiple Micro Frontends integrated in it. Now, when I'm trying to integrate the einstein bot in my application, the close button and minimize button in the chat box are getting enlarged and the UI is not looking proper. But if I remove the MFE's from the application, it's working just fine without any issues. Does anyone has any idea about why the CSS of the chat box is getting affected ?